# How to find a 'good' seed page for a web crawler?

Tags: web, internet, web-crawler

I started building a web crawler and read somewhere that it's a very hard problem to find a good seed page for the crawler. Can anyone explain me if there is any pre-defined procedure/ guidlines of finding a good seed page? or how you say that a particular page is a good seed page?

Comment: I have no actual experience on this, but I'd probably start with wikipedia or something like that.

Comment: This question may be better suited to the webmaster's stack exchange site [seo tag](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/seo) (and it may already be answered there too).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A good seed page needs to have

- As many links as possible
- For as many different topics as possible

That's all, really. The first things that come to mind would be Wikipedia and the [Open Directory Project](http://www.dmoz.org/).

Comment: I maintain a project for extracting all external links from wikipedia: https://github.com/lovasoa/wikipedia-externallinks-fast-extraction

Answer (score -1):

Since I believe generalistic web search should be now considered a *solved problem* with a *single provider* that has such an headstart, and momentum, that it's unpractical, unconvenient, and kinda lame to even consider outrunning it, I believe you might prefer focusing your search efforts on a **specialized domain**.

> e.g.: U.S. law, E.U. law, local laws of certain foreign countries,
>   documents in a certain language, fishing, hunting, the military,
>   ambientalism, indian car manifacturers, south american team games,
>   russian motorsports...

Specializing your domains is all about finding the **appropriate** seeds for the given domain. (Also, IMHO, a handul of selected, *unknowing*, specialized forums should also be considered as a starting point) So once you have you domain, if you dig it well, (or at least the one you're working with/for does) the seeds should come natural.

Otherwise head for [dmoz.org](http://dmoz.org) like Google did some 15 years ago. (And don't forget to weight in [yahoo.com](http://yahoo.com) for good measure) Give your crawler another 15 years and you should have a good link base to search upon.

> Ok, ok, if you really really must take this *hard and pointeless* route
>   also consider: [reddit.com](http://twitter.com), [twitter.com](http://twitter.com), and  (why not) the
>   [stackexchange.com](http://stackexchange.com) constellation.

Comment: he's not trying to compete with google, it's probably just a for-fun project

Comment: Sites where users post masses of content including many links would be a good choice - I think they should links to a diverse range of sites. So I definitely agree with your reddit, twitter, stackexchange suggestion.